# Is there a (discrete) monoid M injecting into its group completion G for which BM is not homotopy equivalent to BG?

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology, semigroups-and-monoids, classifying-spaces

For a (discrete) monoid $M$, the classifying space $BM$ is the
geometric realization of the nerve of the one object category whose
hom-set is $M$. (This definition gives the usual classfiying space
when $M$ is a group.) The group completion of $M$ can be constructed
as the fundamental group of $BM$, and is characterized by the
universal property that any monoid homomorphism from $M$ to a group
factors uniquely through the group completion.

My question is whether there is an example of a monoid for which the
canonical map to its group completion is injective, but for which this
canonical map does not induce a homotopy equivalence of the
classifying spaces.

As background here are some facts:

1. Classifying spaces of monoids produce all connected homotopy types!
   This is proved in Dusa McDuff's 1979 paper *On the classifying spaces
   of discrete monoids*. For a neat concrete example, see Zbigniew
   Fiedorowicz's [*A counterexample to a group completion conjecture of
   JC Moore*](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202260); it shows a specific 5
   element monoid whose classifying space is homotopy equivalent to $S^2$.
2. If $G$ is the group completion of a *commutative* monoid $M$, the
   canonical map $BM \to BG$ is a homotopy equivalence; even if $M \to G$
   is *not* injective. (This is easy to prove: think of $M \to G$ as a
   functor between one object categories and apply Quillen's Theorem A to
   it. There is only one slice category to check and using commutativity
   it is easy to see this category is filtered and thus contractible.)
3. If $M$ is a free monoid and the free group $G$ is its completion,
   the map $BM \to BG$ is a homotopy equivalence. It fact, more
   generally, if $C$ is the free category on some directed graph $X$, the
   nerve of $C$ is homotopy equivalent to the geometric realization of
   $X$. This is proved in Dwyer and Kan's [*Simplical Localization of
   Categories*](http://www.nd.edu/~wgd/Dvi/SimplicialLocalizations.pdf),
   proposition 2.9, but the proof is simple enough to sketch here: for
   each $k$, the inclusion of the $k$-skeletion of $NC$ into the
   $(k+1)$-skeleton is a weak homotopy equivalence (since you get the
   $(k+1)$-skeleton by filling in some horns); so the $1$-skeleton,
   $X$, is weakly equivalent to $NC$. (The claim for free monoids is
   the case where $X$ consists of a single vertex with some loops.)
4. Even if a monoid has left and right cancellation the canonical map
   to its group completion might not be injective. Here's an example from
   Malcev's *On the Immersion of an Algebraic Ring into a Field*: let $M$
   be the *monoid* presented by $(a,b,c,d,x,y,u,v : ax=by, cx=dy,
      au=bv)$. Malcev shows that $M$ is cancellative, but that in $M$, $cu
      \neq dv$; in any group the relations listed for $M$ would imply that
   $cu=dv$.

Comment: If the monoid satisfies an Ore condition then the classifying spaces are equivalent. 

Comment: Is an Ore condition something like having a right calculus of fractions? If so, the proof sketched in 2 covers this case as well. I forgot to mention that, thanks Benjamin.

Comment: Yes Ore=calculus of fractions. 

Comment: Spice the bird seems to answer that no examples exist in his/her answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94017/why-is-the-the-classifying-space-of-the-natural-numbers-homotopy-equivalent-to-th/94018#94018. I never completely understood his/her answer so would be grateful if someone could. 

Comment: I don't understand Spice the bird's argument. He or she seems to be saying that for a "cancelable" M, NKM is obtained from NM by attaching files for outer horns, in particular, by only adding simplices, so it would seem the argument would imply that M injects into KM, but Malcev's example shows that's not always true. (Maybe "cancelable" means "injects into KM" rather than "has left and right cancellation" in Spice's answer?)

Comment: I'm also confused by talk of "minimal fibrations" in Spice the bird's answer since there is no map NZ->NN and the inclusion NN->NZ is not a fibration, of course. I think Spice might have meant NKM is a minimal simplicial set or something like that instead...

Comment: Plus, it id's not true that just adding fillers for the outer horns of NM gets you NKM, since you also have compositions of elements of KM\M.

Comment: In Fiedorowicz, Z. Classifying spaces of topological monoids and categories. Amer. J. Math. 106 (1984), no. 2, 301–350 it is shown that the natural map $BM\to BG$ is a homotopy equivalence if and ony if $H_n(M,\mathbb ZG)=0$ for $n\geq 1$. 

Comment: That's a nice paper, thanks for the reference, @BenjaminSteinberg!

Comment: If I understood correctly the classifying space of the slice category is the universal cover of BM. So it is contractible iff BM is a K(G,1).  The homology of this slice category is the homology of M with coefficients in ZG. In particular BM is homotopy equivalent to BG iff the canonical map is an equivalence. 

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Alternatively, instead of using the universal cover argument, I think you can use Quillen's theorem B to show the slice category is simply connected, and thus contractible iff it has trivial homology, in which case Theorem B implies the canonical map is an equivalence BM->BG.

Comment: In semigroup jargon the 5-element example with classifying space $S^2$ is a 2x2 rectangular band with adjoined identity. 